# Join two tables on multiple columns and return only records from first table that are not in the second

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have table 1 with data and table 2 as a lookup table with metadata. I need a query that  returns all records from table 1 where either column in table 1 not exists in table two.
The following query works fine for one column, but if I use more than one column in my join it´s not.
working query:

```
select
T1.SCENARIO,
T1.year,
T1.period,
T1.ENTITY,
T1.account,
T1.ICP,
T1.MVMTS,
T1.C1,
T1.C2,
T1.C3,
T1.MULTI_GAAP,
T1.VLAUE
```

from
    "fccs".MV_FACT_FCCS T1
    left outer join "fccs".V_META_NOT_FOUND V2 on trim(T1.account) = trim(V2.account)

where
    V2.account is null

not working correctly:

```
select
T1.SCENARIO,
T1.year,
T1.period,
T1.ENTITY,
T1.account,
T1.ICP,
T1.MVMTS,
T1.C1,
T1.C2,
T1.C3,
T1.MULTI_GAAP,
T1.VLAUE
```

from
    "fccs".MV_FACT_FCCS T1
    left outer join "fccs".V_META_NOT_FOUND V2 on trim(T1.account) = trim(V2.account)
                                                  and trim(T1.entity) = trim(v2.entity)

where
    V2.account is null or v2.entity is null

The second query continues to bring the records from table 1 where exist in table 2.
Any help appreciated!

[image: table1]

[image: table2]

Answer (score 0):

> I need a query that returns all records from table 1 where either column in table 1 not exists in table two.

Use `not exists`:

```
select ff.*
from "fccs".MV_FACT_FCCS ff
where not exists (select 1
                  from "fccs".V_META_NOT_FOUND mnf
                  where trim(ff.account) = trim(mnf.account)
                 ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from "fccs".V_META_NOT_FOUND mnf
                  where trim(ff.entity) = mnf.trimc
                 ) ;
```

Note:  This answers the question *as written*.  You might mean that *both* conditions are not met.  In that case, use `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: Thank you so much! However is not working, my result still returns records for account that are in table 2.

Comment: @user1766419 . . . Replace the `or` with `and` as the answer proposed.